# Which statistical analysis? R

Tags: r, regression, modeling, missing-data

I'm just getting started in R and I'm trying to wrap my head around an analysis for a university assignment. Specifically, I am using the General Social Survey 2018 dataset (for codebook: https://www.thearda.com/Archive/Files/Codebooks/GSS2018_CB.asp) and I am trying to figure out if religion has any effect on the way people seek out help for mental health. I want to use `reliten` (self-assessment of religiousness - from strong to no religion) as the IV and `mentloth`, (asks if a person with mental health issues should reach out to a mental health professional - yes or no) as the DV. At first, I thought a chi-square would be the best option but I'm not so sure anymore because R is treating all of the response options as numerical, not categorical.

1. Taking this into consideration, should I run a regression instead?
2. Regardless of the analysis, how do I make sure R doesn't take into consideration the "Not applicable", "Don't know" and "No response" values coded as 0, 8 and 9?

Below there is a short preview of my data

```
structure(list(reliten = structure(c(1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
4, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1), label = "Would you call yourself a strong [religious preference] or a not very strong [re", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(`Not applicable` = 0, 
Strong = 1, `Not very strong` = 2, `Somewhat strong` = 3, `No religion` = 4, 
`Don't know` = 8, `No answer` = 9), class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double")), mentloth = structure(c(0, 1, 0, 1, 
2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0
), label = "Should [NAME] go to a therapist, or counselor, like a psychologist, social worke", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(`Not applicable` = 0, 
Yes = 1, No = 2, `Don't know` = 8, `No answer` = 9), class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double"))), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi @Elisabeth. With a binary dependent variable (a yes/no response), it may be suitable for you to run a 'logistic regression,' and thus evaluate probabilities associated with yes/no responses conditional upon religious status. However, I would argue that even if logistic regression was the correct set-up, you might want to avoid univariate analysis. Including variables beyond religious status will yield a more complete understanding of demand for mental health services.

Comment: @Elisabeth. When it comes to removing NAs, don't knows, and non-responses; then look up 'filtering' data protocols in R.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Maybe **start** by making a $2 \times 5$ table with rows Y/N and columns for strength of religious belief (1 through 4, and 5 for DK/NA combined). Then use `chisq.test` on the table to see row and column categories are independent. Then the cell counts will be used as such. Chi-sq test treats Religion as nominal, not ordinal, so you may want to do a logistic regression if the table seems interesting. // May be useful to try to collect info on specific religions. Some religions have strong core beliefs about causes of mental health issues; it might be useful to know their actual consequences.

Comment: @BruceET, thank you! how can I create the 2x5 table?

Comment: I agree with @EB3112's answer.  One addition: you should code reliten as a factor variable instead of numeric.